# How do I perform a melee takedown?

Tags: battlefield-1, battlefield-1-beta

In FPS games stealth takedowns are usually performed when approaching a target from behind (crouching) and pressing the melee key. Enemies have often killed me with a finisher move in Battlefield 1.
How instant stealth kills work? One possibility is to run and hold melee to do a bayonet charge, but that can't be the only way as it wouldn't work in close quarters.

**UPDATE**: This likely was an issue with the beta, melee finishers now function as expected.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the usual knife animation has been removed (you could move straight from a gun to knifing someone), it is not mentioned on [this](http://battlefield.wikia.com/wiki/Knife_Takedown) page for the take-downs on the battlefield wiki. Instead, a melee weapon must be equipped and used, as seen in [this](https://youtu.be/Gl5oIIarMxs?t=1m42s) video.

Comment: Do I have to run in order to perform a charge?

Comment: I believe i have been knifed from behind by a player, perhaps it only works if you have an actual knife equiped.

Comment: @Vahx was right, answer was amended.

Comment: From my own experience, there are still assassination animations for other weapons, such as the shovel, and it doesnt need to be equipped manually either, it can be done with rifle in hand, by holding down the melee button (much easier from rear, as this answer's first link confirms). A quick tap of the melee will just do the regular quick strike, even from behind, i believe.